# strcmp struct in c - different elements

Tags: c, struct, strcmp

I have a struct member that holds lots of string elements. What I want is to iterate the whole member of the struct and count only different elements (diff last names).

```
struct log {
    char *last;
};
...
struct log *l
l->last = last_name; // loading *last member with data coming from last_name var
...
```

What would be a good way to compare and count unique elements currently on ***last**?

Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: well, what Im asking is a good way on how to compare each of those elements and get the only the unique ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your array on the `last_name` key. Duplicates will be next to each other.

Do a linear sweep through the array, checking how many entries after the current item have the same last name. Increment your counter once for all these duplicates. Increment your read-head to the first distinct entry.

For an array of size `n`: `O(n lg n) + O(n) = O(n lg n)` operations, assuming an `O(n lg n)` sort routine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over several items, it is a whole lot easier if these items are in an array. Could you consider redefining your `struct` definition to include the items in an array? You could perhaps index into the array using an `enum` or even a series of `#define`s.

If your data can't sensibly go into an array, you are likely to end up with a solution which looks like comparing the value with each item in the struct one at a time.